# How to select from a dynamic column through a variable with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a PHP variable `$col` with a column name. I want to create a query with PDO, that selects the value of that column. I know how to use `bindValue()`, and tried the following:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='. $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function get_user($id, $column){

    $sql = "
        SELECT :col
        FROM users
        WHERE `id` = :id;";

    try {
        $st = $db->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue('col', $column, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $st->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $result = $st->fetch();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Database query exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

That results in the following exception: `Database query exception: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ''name'' in 'field list'` for `$col = 'name'`. Of course, the column `name` does exist.

It works well on `WHERE = :value`, but I can not get it working for a column. How to achieve this?

Addition: I did found the function `bindColumn()`, but I think that does the opposite, binding the column name to a PHP variable instead of binding a variable to the column.

Comment: (Sorry, but I couldn't get the code block right marked up with the backticks.)

Comment: You can't do this through parameter binding - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15990488/1233508) for reasons. You will need to sanitize that column name and add it to the query manually.

Comment: Not possible. placeholders can only represent VALUES in a query, never a column or field name. You'll have to use good-old [sql-injection-vulnerable](http://bobby-tables.com) `SELECT $field FROM $table`-type string construction methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array of allowed column names to sanitize the query.

```
$allowed_columns = array('name', 'type1',etc);//Array of allowed columns to sanatise query
```

Then check if column name is in array.

```
if (in_array($column, $allowed_columns)){
      $result= get_user($id, $column);
}
function get_user($id, $column){

    $sql = "
        SELECT $column
        FROM users
        WHERE `id` = :id;";

    try {
        $st = $db->prepare($sql);
        $st->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $st->execute();
        $result = $st->fetch();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Database query exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use **array_intersect** something like a sanitizing function that would extract only the allowed fields. Example:

```
function get_fields_allowed($input_fields,$allowed){
  $input_fields=explode(",",$input_fields);
  $allowed=explode(",",$allowed);
  return array_intersect($allowed,$input_fields);
}


$select_fields=$_POST["fields"];  //example: "id,name,email"

$fields=get_fields_allowed ($select_fields, "id,name" ) ;
```

So you then use the $fields as in:

```
$sql="Select $fields FROM [table] WHERE id=:id etc...";
```

Comment: That is an easy one, but that does not use PDO.

Comment: @BasC yes you can use PDO. This only refers to the $fields because you are only allowing the "cols" that you list there, so its safe. The other part of the string (e.g Where id=:id) which can be from user input you can still compose your self, using whatever you like.

Comment: @BasC there is NO solution that could use PDO. Go figure.