# Is it Safe to Send a Table Name in as Parameter

Tags: php, class, security, pdo

I am new to PDO and am creating a class. I want to make the code as clean as possible and have a few pages as possible. I am planning on sending the column and table names in as a parameter:

```
   function get($column, $table, $where) {
        global $db;
        $query = 'SELECT '.$column.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$where.'';
        try {
            $statement = $db->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute();
            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
            $statement->closeCursor();
            return $result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $error_message = $e->getMessage();
            display_db_error($error_message);
        }
   }
```

It works fine, but I am wondering how safe it would be considered.

Comment: Your code is unsafe. Unless you're testing $column, $table and $where some place else in your code, this is ripe for sql injection. I wouldn't do what you plan on doing. It's a path to crazy bugs and errors. Allowing the user to control what table is accessed is obviously a major flaw in your application design.

Comment: Thank you. That was what I was wondering. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. If you want write less code, I recommend using a framework like Symfony. It gets you our of the nitty gritty coding and working at a higher level.

Comment: @gnarly is right, and that should be an answer. PDO is safe when you use [bind parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php), but not when you concatenate strings.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer.

Comment: My other issue is that I want this where statement: WHERE id = :id AND otherid = :otherid but I might not always have an "id" or "otherid". So my plan was to pass "id = :id AND otherid = :otherid" in as a parameter, so I could change it if I had, too. If I can't do this, how else would you suggest doing it? Without making a separate function....

Comment: Relating to an earlier point: Symfony itself doesn't handle databases, as far as I know. However it uses Doctrine, an ORM, which simplifies access to databases - so whilst web frameworks are in general a good idea, it's the ORM that will help here, not the web framework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select from a dynamic column through a variable with PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283141/how-to-select-from-a-dynamic-column-through-a-variable-with-pdo)

Comment: @davidstrachan, no it is not the same. I was asking about the security issues with my code, unlike the other post.

Comment: It shows you how to sanitize table & column names to stop your query being vulnerabe to SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is unsafe. Unless you're testing $column, $table and $where some place else in your code, this is ripe for sql injection. I wouldn't do what you plan on doing. It's a path to crazy bugs and errors. Allowing the user to control what table is accessed is obviously a major flaw in your application design.