# How can I insert variables in mysql SET when Updating?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What ways can I use variables in Mysql Update SET? I'm trying to pass variables but I don't know if that's really how it's done and if it's safe;

How am I doing:

```
$update = $this->pdo->prepare(
  "UPDATE `user_info`
  SET '$name' = ? //This way
  WHERE unique_token = ?"
);

$update->execute(array($value, $unique_token));
```

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: @Barmar Do I run any risk doing it this way?

Comment: I generally prefer to use named parameters instead of `?`, but other than that it's the right way to do it.

Comment: Wait a second. Why do you have `$name` inside quotes? You can't assign to a string.

Comment: The main issue with `'$name'` is that columns should be surrounded by ticks, not single quotes, and make sure that you know that `$name` contains a safe value (either one you've specified or a value that you've checked against a list of potentials)

Comment: I didn't notice the variable `$name` earlier. See @aynber's caveats.

Comment: See this for an example of dynamic column validation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288160/231316